# Type Cast NSString to Integer iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting, integer, nsstring

I want to typeCast following NSString into integer, I tried multiple things but not Working :

```
Nsstring *myString = @"123456  | 2333444 | 33333 | 3555";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
NSString *myString = @"123456  | 2333444 | 33333 | 3555";
NSArray *numbers = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
for(NSString *number in numbers)
    NSLog(@"%d",[number intValue]);
```

Comment: What about |, causing issue due to | only ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking.